# Polymer component method is not accessible from chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, polymer, web-component

I'm creating polymer element in chrome extension and injecting it to webpage. Components looks something like this:

```
<dom-module id="foo">

  <template is="auto-binding">
    <div>Foo</div>
  </template>

  <script>
    class Foo extends Polymer.Element {

      static get is() {
        return "foo";
      }

      log() {
        console.log('foo');
      }

    }
    customElements.define(Foo.is, Foo);
  </script>

</dom-module>
```

I'm injecting it to HTML with in my content script with this:

```
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
  <div>
  <script src="${chrome.extension.getURL('webcomponents/webcomponents-loader.js')}"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="${chrome.extension.getURL('polymer/polymer.html')}">
  <link rel="import" href="${chrome.extension.getURL('components/foo.html')}">
  <foo></foo>
  </div>
`);
```

It works fine, and when I run `document.querySelector('foo').log()` in browser console or in webpage, that I'm injecting to I see log messages.

But when I'm trying to do something like

```
setTimeout(() => {
  document.querySelector('foo').log()
}, 5000);
```

inside my content script I'm receiving error

> document.querySelector(...).log is not a function

`document.querySelector('foo')` returns `<foo></foo>` node as expected.

So, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Content script runs in an *isolated world*. You'll have to insert the setTimeout code inside a script element too. See also: [Insert code into the page context using a content script](//stackoverflow.com/a/9517879)

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: For security reasons, *functional* `<script>` elements *can not* be created directly from HTML text. you *must* create them using [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement), or other non-HTML-text method (e.g. [`.cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode)).